# Get selected row in Gridview (dxexprince 10 aspx.net)?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

Im new on Dxpreince 10.(and don't think im expert on this)
I wrote simple webpage. For setting values in grid view i use list and bind that to `Aspxgridview.Datasouce`. so how access to the selected row ?(plz help with sample code)
I want to get this value in `my self defined method not in Selection-changed method! and access to all part of this record no one part of that`

**should use client-side event**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the FocusedRowIndex property?

Documentation:
[FocusedRowIndex](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FocusedRowIndextopic)

Answer (score 0):

Use the

> ASPxGridView.GetRow(ASPxGridView.FocusedRowIndex)

method for this purpose.

Comment: so i solve my problem with this property, but u need to set `SettingsBehavior-AllowFocusedRow` to true , then "FocusedRowIndex" return index of selected row